# why can't the my MVC controller find it's view when unit tested

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We use moq and mstest to unit test our controllers however for some reason when we test a method which returns a view it can't seem to load the view. The ViewResult object always returns null for the View property (i.e. ViewResult.View = null).

I have tried copying it to the bin folder of mstest project and to the output folder (i.e. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BrandingEngine\TestResults\steve_MYPC 2013-05-15 08_44_43\Out)

Answer (score 1):

For your unit tests, you should test the ViewResult.ViewName property.

There's no need to test the built-in view resolution. You just need to check whether your controller is really returning the correct View.

Note: if you're returning the standard View ( `return View();` ), the `ViewName`-property will be null. This is the expected behavior, because again, you don't want to unit test the built-in view resolution, you want to test whether the controller is returning the default view.